# Csv to Json converter tool

Tags: json, csv, avro

I have a csv file which I want to convert to Avro; because there are no tools to convert directly from csv to avro, i decided to use an online tool to convert from csv to json and then I plan to write a small program to convert that json to convert to an avro model. 
The problem I have is that the csv file looks like this

H1, H2, H3
------------------
A1, A2, A3, A4, A4
B1, B2, B3, B4
C1, C2, C3

every column after H3 is part of the H3 array.
The existing tools dont seem to have this feature included (this one says it does, but im not sure how to use it: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm).
Does anybody know how to deal with this.

Thanks,
Shripadsrd

Comment: Do you have any existing code that processes that csv file currently? If so where does it store the output it reads from the csv file? It may be easier to convert that output to JSON is what I am thinking.

Comment: I dont have code to process csv, i have code to process json into avro. i was hoping to have an online tool convert csv to json for me.

Comment: I am the creator of convertcsv.com and you can do this on the CSV to JSON page - 1. Paste data into text area. 2. Press the CSV to JSON button. Contact me on website for details if you need help.

Comment: I'm not clear about the question... can you provide the JSON that you expect to be outputted given the input data you provided? Something like this? `{ "H1":"A1","H2":"A2","H3":["A4","A4"] }`

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished in Powershell.

```
Import-Csv "foo.csv" | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "foo.json"
```

You can add the -compress switch to remove newlines too

```
Import-Csv "foo.csv" | ConvertTo-Json -compress | Add-Content -Path "foo.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is wrapping your JSON result based on some nesting parameters. Basically going from this :

```
H1, H2, H3
------------------
A1, A2, A3, A4, A4
B1, B2, B3, B4
C1, C2, C3
```

To this:

```
[
    {
        "H1": "A1",
        "H2": "A2",
        "H3": [
            "A3",
            "A4",
            "A4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "H1": "B1",
        "H2": "B2",
        "H3": [
            "B3",
            "B4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "H1": "C1",
        "H2": "C2",
        "H3": [
            "C3"
        ]
    }
]
```

I created a tool to solve this type of problems at http://csvtojson.com

What you need to do, is adapt your header so that it explicitly states how you want to nest your result.
For your example, it would look like :

```
H1, H2, H3.0, H3.1, H3.2
A1, A2, A3, A4, A4
B1, B2, B3, B4
C1, C2, C3
```

Notice how `H3` is repeated using dots `H3.0`, `H3.1`, `H3.2`: these dots represents how you want to wrap your results into an `H3` array. Eventually, press the "Convert button" and your result will be prompted to you.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familar with Avro but the following [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filter will perform the transformation 
[Jona Rodrigues](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7959116/jona-rodrigues) describes.  Specifically: if the file `filter.jq` contains

```
[
  split("\n")                           # split string into lines
| (.[0]    | split(",")) as $headers    # split header
| (.[1:][] | split(","))                # split data rows
| select(length>0)                      # get rid of empty lines
| $headers[:-1] as $h1                  # fixed headers
| .[:($h1|length)] as $p1               # fixed part
| .[($h1|length):] as $p2               # variable part
| (
     [   [ $h1, $p1 ]                   # \  
       | transpose[]                    #  \ assemble fixed object
       | {key:.[0], value:.[1]}         #  / from fixed keys and values
     ] | from_entries                   # /
  ) + {
     ($headers[-1]): $p2                # assemble variable object
  }
]
```

and `data` contains

```
H1,H2,H3
A1,A2,A3,A4,A4
B1,B2,B3,B4
C1,C2,C3
```

then the command

```
jq -M -R -s -r -f filter.jq data
```

will produce

```
[
  {
    "H1": "A1",
    "H2": "A2",
    "H3": [
      "A3",
      "A4",
      "A4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "H1": "B1",
    "H2": "B2",
    "H3": [
      "B3",
      "B4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "H1": "C1",
    "H2": "C2",
    "H3": [
      "C3"
    ]
  }
]
```